# Passing only one parameter to map instead of two in Scheme

Tags: scheme, guile

I have a function in scheme `(extract-disjunct word nodes)` that takes two parameters: `word` and `nodes`.

I have a sentence: "This is a test sentence". For each word in this sentence I want to apply the above given function.

This can be done with a simple map operation.

However, the catch is this:
The second parameter `nodes` is itself a nested list and the parameter stays the same for a given sentence i.e it will stay the same for the list of words that I intend to apply map to. It won't change.

I want to apply map like this:
`(map extract-disjunct word nodes)`

However, I receive an error. Is there any solution? Can I keep one parameter in map constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply define another function that takes the `word` argument and passes it and a constant `nodes` argument to `extract-disjunct`. Using currying, you can make this work for any constant `nodes`:

```
(define ((curried-extract-disjunct nodes) word) (extract-disjunct word nodes))

(map (curried-extract-disjunct nodes) words)
```